# Webpage not expiring after browser's backbutton click in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a login page, after login i am redirecting to profile page where users can logout, after logout i am again redirecting to same login page, and i have used the following methods to clear the browser session(I am using IE 8 and FireFox).  but they are not working. When I click back button in Login page, previous page is displaying instead of webpage expire message.

```
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(false);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60));
    Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
```

Here we are using same master page for both login page and profile page after login. And I have added the above methods In both master page and in login page. But they are not working. Suggest me some solution, when user clicks back button in browser after logout, then webpage must expired.

Comment: Page displayed by back button is from browser history you may need to think about that.

Comment: You are clearing cache in these lines of code, how are you clearing login information?

Comment: @Waqa Raja, In logout link button click event i am using Session.Abonden(0, Session.Clear() methods

Comment: @Mairaj Ahmad, Thanks for the reply, but i am clearing the browser's history then how, browser will remember the history

Comment: @SantoshKumar you cannot clear browser's history, just to check each request if the user is authorized otherwise redirect it to Login screen

Comment: @Waqas Raja, when users clicks back button of browser, then webpage expired message need to be displayed, like banking application.

Comment: for that purpose you need to add an intermediate page (for logout functionality) on that you will check if session is expired then redirect to login page otherwise clear the session and redirect to login page.

Comment: @WaqasRaja, Thanks for the reply, cant I do in login page itself, Actual the thing is,some times the web page is expiring ie..the above methods are working, but some times they are not working. Please can u suggest any improvement in the above methods so that they can work every time when user click back button in broweser.

Comment: you cannot do this in single page and you need to put the cache expiring lines on other pages as well. then create another page eg. `Logout.aspx` on that page apply the logout and redirect to login page logic

Comment: @Waqas Raja, Thanks for the reply, I will Implement It now